# Error Loading and Deleting Images using HTML Input File Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I desperately need help with an issue I am having while trying load an image or unload an image using ASP/C#. The problem I am having is the first time I run the code and Load the image into the thumbnail, I have no problem but the minute I try to remove the picture or load a second or third image, it takes very very long to hit the event and I get an Out of Memory error. I think something is getting locked and takes a while to get unlocked but I am not sure.

Here is the code I am using:

```
protected void btnUploadImgPicture1_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (filePicture1)
        {
            if (filePicture1.PostedFile.FileName != &quot;&quot;)
            {
                imageUtil = new ImageUtility();
                string realPhysicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(&quot;~/upload/&quot;), filePicture1.PostedFile.FileName);
                filePicture1.PostedFile.SaveAs(realPhysicalPath);
                //imgVehiclePicture1.Src = realPhysicalPath;
                using (imgVehiclePicture1)
                {
                    imgVehiclePicture1.Attributes[&quot;src&quot;] = imageUtil.getBase64String(realPhysicalPath);
                    Session.Add(&quot;Image1&quot;, realPhysicalPath);
                    imageUtil = null;
                }

            }
        }
    }

 public  string getBase64String(string path)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
        byte[] imageBytes = imageToByteArray(img);
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        return "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
    }
```

I am using this code on 3 times for 3 different events and then I am using similar code to remove the selected image from the upload.

Comment: You are not using `using` blocks correctly. You should almost certainly just not use them unless you are creating things like `filePicture1`. I suspect that `filePicture1` is a control on your page, in which case, your code is not creating it, so your code should not be disposing of it.

Comment: I removed all the usings and I added one using to a different method.
 public  string getBase64String(string path)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
            using (img)
            {
                byte[] imageBytes = imageToByteArray(img);
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                return "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
            }
        }
Now,  after the first event fires. Then I get an Out of Memory error on the second fire of the event on the Line: Image img = Image.FromFile(path);

Comment: Update your question with that information, and tell us if you still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is ImageUtility? If it implements IDisposable then you might want to try explicitly disposing it instead of setting the variable to null. Even better if you can wrap it inside of a using block.

Comment: Hi, The ImageUtiliy is the class with

 public  string getBase64String(string path)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
            byte[] imageBytes = imageToByteArray(img);
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            return "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
        }

It does not implement IDisposible. Can you please tell me the benefit of doing that?

Comment: Ensure that you don't have any object holding onto file references or image graphics libraries. Either of these could certainly explain the behavior that you are seeing.